# Twitter Gem and Rails issue saving user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

im building an application that extracts all mentions using twitter, i have a Profile model where i want to save all the users that sent a mention. On that table i have twitter_id field where i want to store the id retrieved through the twitter API.. and other fields like description, screen_name etc that have the same names.

```
  # a.tc is a Twitter object already authenticated
  tws = a.tc.mentions({:count => 200})

  # foreach mention
  tws.each do |t|
    # Check if we already have it saved
    p = Profile.find_by_twitter_id t.user.id
    if p.nil?
      # Profile doesnt exist, try to save it
      p = Profile.new(t.user.to_hash) # ERROR!
      p.twitter_id = t.user.id
      p.save
    end
```

I already tried many things but everything trows an error... im a ruby noob =P

Comment: Why do you use `Profile.new(t.user.to_hash)`, what exactly is the error and what are you trying to do there?

Comment: t.user is a User object from Twitter gem and i created the Profile table to have SOME of the keys from t.user (Twitter::User) as fields, for example: screen_name, description, location, but some other key doesnt exists in my model cause im not interested in all data. the error is : "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id" I understand the error but how i can save the user into the profile or i have to create a hash with each field im interested doesnt care it shares the same name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either delete the ID or assign only the attributes that are available in `Profile`:

```
  usr = t.user.to_hash
  usr.delete :id # or "id", I'm not sure how the Hash looks like exactly
  ## delete all the other keys that are not neccessary
  p = Profile.new usr
```

or **use this way**. This is the better way because you cannot assign attributes by accident

```
 p = Profile.new (:screen_name => t.user.screen_name, ... and so on... )
```

Comment: Seems like this should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: No, this is an answer to the OP's question, from what I can gather.

Comment: Also, I would go with the latter way. Since you only want some keys, it's better to be explicit about those, instead of removing the others. If you had wanted, say, all attributes except for the screenname, then I would go with the "delete key" method.